# Looking for a good C++/.net book

Tags: .net, c++

I have recently started to feel that I need to greatly improve my C++ skills especially in the realm of .net.  I graduated from a good four year university with a degree in computer science about 9 months ago and I have since been doing full time contract work for a small software company in my local area.  Most of my work has been done using Java/lisp/cocoa/XML and before that most of my programming in my senior year was in java/C#.  I did a decent amount of C++ in my Sophomore year and in my free time before that but I feel that my general knowledge of C++/.net is very lacking for the opportunities that are now coming my way.  Can anyone recommend a good book that could help me get up too speed?  I feel I do not need a very basic introduction to C++ but something that covers the fundamentals of .net would be good for me.  So basically what I need is a book or books that would be good for a .net novice and a C++ developer who is just beyond novice.  Also, a book that would help bein an interview by giving me a conversional understanding of C++ would be great.  Thanks a lot!.

Comment: You could improve the question title

Comment: C++ isn't a .NET language. Are you asking about C++ *and* .NET, or C++/CLI (the .NET variant of C++) or... something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends what you actually want to learn:

- If you want to learn about .Net, I would learn C# rather than C++.
- If you want to learn C++, do not learn C++/CLI - learn the language described by the C++ Standard. For C++ books, see [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). I personally would recommend [Accelerated C++](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest [C++/CLI In Action](http://www.manning.com/sivakumar/).  It's one of the few C++/CLI books specifically discussion the issues that arise when mixing .NET into C++.

Comment: There's also [Expert C++/CLI](https://www.amazon.de/Expert-CLI-Visual-Programmers-Experts/dp/1590597567). Do you know it? Can you recommend it?